# In search of simple color position correction for comic books

Tags: color, registration

Is there a very simple and basic program that will separate colors and let me shift the position of one or another?  I'm looking at correcting old comic book panels which sometimes have a color way out of position.

Thank you.

Comment: This may in fact be harder than you think because of the difference between rgb and whatever color plates the comic uses. Not impossible by any means though. I would have to run some tests to know for sure.

Comment: Do you have an example image?

Comment: The catch is the overprinting will make this hard. Not impossible, but hard. FYI, the mis-registration of old cheap comic printing is part of its charm. I'd not worry about it and just accept it as 'patina of the time'.

Comment: It -is- the patina of the time, but when the red is halfway across the page, I'd like to see it in place.  Plus when I share pictures, it's just polite to have them look properly.

Comment: Related: http://4cp.posthaven.com/in-defense-of-dots-the-lost-art-of-comic-book

Answer (score 3):

While this is certainly possible its not very easy. You can try using 3 hue saturation layers that you adjust for the colors used (cyan, magenta altough in this comic it was red, and yellow) as separate layers to +100 lightness. You can then copy merged to get the black layer.

Put the black layer on top and divide the underlying layers with that. You now have eliminated black. Unhide each hue saturation at a time copy merged for each individual layer and you will have each layer separated. Thsi takes some tweaking to get done correctly and most likely blank channel suffers a bit of flooding from other layers unless you scan is extraordinarily good quality.

[image]

**Image 1**: Quick before before and after moving individual layers. Image form [here](http://cartoonsnap.blogspot.fi/2007/10/ape-escapes-museum-mayhem-more-super.html)

In reality i should use a lot of time to fix the black layer so i can get better estimates for the other colors. As this technique taints the other colors luminance to the black channel. Also instead of hue saturation one should divide back the layers. But this represents a reasonable attack on the problem that is fast to do not the state of the art of attack.

[image]

**Image 2**: Black channel showing how overlapping color regions affect the result. Especially blue red border taint luminosity quite much.

Cleaning up the black, with more time, should make the image much better behaved.

**PS**: The print was interesting in that it didn't have a magenta channel but instead used a clearly redder ink.

**PPS**: the jpeg compression caused me all sorts of grief.

Comment: Thank you for your conscientious reply.  Yes, "magenta" doesn't mean much in the comic book world -- when they want to print red, they print red.  When you say  "Put the black layer on top and divide the underlying layers with that."  I don't know what "divide" means in this context.  I only have experience with relatively simple graphics software.